# Google Maps iOS SDK didTapInfoWindowOfMarker not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have an odd problem where I cannot get this method to do anything! I have added the map view delegate and delcaired the delegate in the top AND header file. I intend to just get a response when the user touches a bubble produced by tapping on a google maps marker

Here is what I have

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Location.h"

@interface ViewController () <GMSMapViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic)NSMutableArray* storedLocations;
@property(nonatomic)NSMutableArray* myPlaces;

@end

@implementation ViewController {

GMSMapView *mapView;

}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker     *)marker{

 UIAlertView* new = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nice!" message:@"Good stuff" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Well Done!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[new show];


}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create Map View on scene with camera
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0
                                                        longitude:0
                                                             zoom:0];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView;
    mapView.delegate = self;
```

As mentioned at the moment, touching the bubble does nothing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if your marker is tapped, you should call the

[(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *) marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#ae291e1bff99f9d06428ced09daf5802d) method

The method you use, it will only been called if the info window of your marker is tapped.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when im back home

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to define a Title,

```
mapView.title = @"Test title";
```

then you can tap over the description window.